# Pass array to setFilter() in Symfony

Tags: arrays, symfony1, filter

I'm using symfony 1.4 with Doctrine ORM and was wondering whether it's  possible to pass an array when using setFilter() as in below?

```
$this->setFilters(array('subcounty_id'=>$array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible for widgets like Select box